# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated - jqueryui dialog/dataTables

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, datatables

I am trying to load up a jQueryUI modal window from a page that contains a dataTables table. The button for the modal window is on a row in the dataTable. Another modal button not on the dataTable works. I get the error:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

I really am having a hard time understanding what this means and how to deal with it. Here is my code:

```
var recdt = $('#LettTable').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
});  

//******Modal edit letter text form
//Following is for popups for simple forms================
var edit_let_url;
$("#edit-let-modal").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 500,
    width: 500,
    modal: true,
    //async:true,
    buttons: {
        "Save": function() {
            $.post(edit_let_url,
                $('#edit-let-form').serializeArray(),
                function(data) {
                    if (data) {

                        //pass ex_id as data for preview redirect

                        window.location.href = "/app/letters_config/";

                    } else {
                        alert('Did not save');
                        $('#edit-let-form').html(data);
                    }
                })
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$('#LettTable').on('click touchstart', '.edit_lett', function() {
    //$('.edit_lett').click( function (){
    edit_let_url = $(this).attr('name');
    $("#edit-let-modal").load(edit_let_url).dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: There is no synchronous AJAX requests in the code you've shown, so we can't give you a relevant solution to the problem. That said, generally this is caused by using `async: false` on a `$.ajax()` request. You should remove that property and place any code reliant on the returned data in the callback function.

Comment: I think I remember someone encountering this if the page you are loading is doing some <script> file include as part of it's markup.

Comment: Do you guys know how I could search for wherever there are synchronous Ajax reqs - like I said I think this is in dt or dialog code - as it only occurs on dialog buttons on the dt

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys - I was passing in the wrong url to the modal - I kind of just discovered this after a walk. It was causing the modal to load with the base page, then nothing - and then screwed up my dt and stuff.